# python IndexError: list index out of range for bounding box

Tags: python, machine-learning, detection, face-detection, bounding-box

i have an issue with my function for extracting faces from image for some reason it detects

some faces but then stops working and print the error.

the issue is with in the line  **x1, y1, width, height = results[0]['box']**

> IndexError: list index out of range

here is my function

```
def extract_face(path_to_filename, detector, required_size=(160, 160), save_faces=True):
    image = Image.open(path_to_filename)  # load image from file
    image = image.convert('RGB')  # convert image to RGB
    pixels = asarray(image)  # convert image to array
    results = detector.detect_faces(pixels)  # detect the face in image by MTCNN
    x1, y1, width, height = results[0]['box']  # extract the bounding box from the face
    x1, y1 = abs(x1), abs(y1)  # avoid bug
    x2, y2 = x1 + width, y1 + height  # avoid bug
    face = pixels[y1:y2, x1:x2]  # extract the face
    image = Image.fromarray(face)  # convert image to its object
    image = image.resize(required_size)  # resize image
    if save_faces:
        path = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(path_to_filename))[0]  # get the path
        print(path)
        file_name = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(path_to_filename))[1]  # get file names
        print(path_to_filename)
        person_name = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(Path(path)))  # get person name based on folder name

        print(person_name)

        project_folder = Path(path).parent.parent  # go to parent parent directory
        target_folder = os.path.join(project_folder, 'faces_mini_dataset',
                                     person_name)  # set detected face in folder person name and images
        if not os.path.exists(target_folder):  # if not directory
            os.makedirs(target_folder)  # create directory
        target_face_file_path = os.path.join(target_folder,
                                             file_name)  # set detected face in folder person name and images
        print(target_face_file_path)
        image.save(target_face_file_path)  # save images in directory
    face_array = asarray(image)
    return face_array
```

**meesgae log**

> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/venv/bin/python
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/generate_faces_from_image.py
> Using TensorFlow backend. Loading images... ['scarlett', 'zakir',
> 'obama'] Loading scarlett we will load [ 10 ] files from [ scarlett ]
> class ... Loading zakir we will load [ 10 ] files from [ zakir ] class
> ... Loading obama we will load [ 10 ] files from [ obama ] class ...
> File loading completed. load dataset......-> load faces->
> WARNING:tensorflow:From
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:74:
> The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use
> tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:From
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:517:
> The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use
> tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:From
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:4138:
> The name tf.random_uniform is deprecated. Please use tf.random.uniform
> instead.
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:From
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3976:
> The name tf.nn.max_pool is deprecated. Please use tf.nn.max_pool2d
> instead.
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:From
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:174:
> The name tf.get_default_session is deprecated. Please use
> tf.compat.v1.get_default_session instead.
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:From
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:181:
> The name tf.ConfigProto is deprecated. Please use
> tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto instead.
>
> Extracting faces from
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/persons_dataset/scarlett/
> .....
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/persons_dataset/scarlett
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/persons_dataset/scarlett/contrast4_image.jpg
> scarlett
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/faces_mini_dataset/scarlett/contrast4_image.jpg
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/persons_dataset/scarlett
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/persons_dataset/scarlett/brightness3_image.jpg
> scarlett
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/faces_mini_dataset/scarlett/brightness3_image.jpg
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/persons_dataset/scarlett
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/persons_dataset/scarlett/img_blue_2.jpg
> scarlett
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/faces_mini_dataset/scarlett/img_blue_2.jpg
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/persons_dataset/scarlett
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/persons_dataset/scarlett/brightness4_image.jpg
> scarlett
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/faces_mini_dataset/scarlett/brightness4_image.jpg
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/persons_dataset/scarlett
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/persons_dataset/scarlett/img_blue_1.jpg
> scarlett
> /home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/faces_mini_dataset/scarlett/img_blue_1.jpg
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/generate_faces_from_image.py",
> line 90, in 
> faces, labels = generate_faces_from_images(persons_dataset_path)   File
> "/home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/generate_faces_from_image.py",
> line 81, in generate_faces_from_images
> faces1 = extract_faces(path)   File "/home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/generate_faces_from_image.py",
> line 66, in extract_faces
> face = extract_face(path, detector, save_faces=True)   File "/home/mani/Desktop/master/dip/final_project/dip_1/generate_faces_from_image.py",
> line 30, in extract_face
> x1, y1, width, height = results[0]['box']  # extract the bounding box from the face IndexError: list index out of range
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: `results = detector.detect_faces(pixels) ` gives you empty list make sure `detector.detect_faces(pixels)` works well.

Comment: @OsadhiVirochana i am sure it works fine

Comment: when i use one image it is working fine but when i increase images up to 5 it is not working

Comment: Can you print `detector.detect_faces(pixels)` and share the output?

Comment: @OsadhiVirochana <mtcnn.mtcnn.MTCNN object at 0x7f2291895860> it prints this line

Comment: Can you try again with using `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and changing `pixels = plt.imread(path_to_filename)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226766/discussion-between-osadhi-virochana-and-black-snow).